# storing output of a command in a variable

Tags: python, fabric

I have a python fabric file fabfile.py. I wish to store the result of a local command in a variable so that I can test it for various cases. For example I want to do this...

```
substring = "up-to-date"  
msg = local("git pull")
if msg.find(substring) == -1:
   "some action"
```

but I am not able to store the output in "msg variable". How can I do this ?

Answer (score 5):

The way I've done this before is:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'pull'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                                      stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()

if "up-to-date" in out:
   "some action"
```

Comment: this method does not work if I use it for a command with more than two words. i.e I tried this..

    `p = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'fetch', 'origin'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                                      stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    out, err = p.communicate()

    print out`

It did not print any output.
pardon me if I am committing any mistakes, I am new to python programming.
Suggest me a way I can store the o/p for a command of any length.

Comment: @AnkitSahu ```git fetch origin``` doesn't return anything if it doesn't need to. Try it on its own on the command line.

Comment: I know `git fetch origin` will not return anything sometimes, but when there are updates on git repository it surely will, and I am getting the output on command line, but not with this.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution and it is pretty simple. We just need to pass another parameter `capture=true` with `local` to store the output of a command in a variable.

```
substring = "up-to-date"
msg = local("git pull", capture=true)
if substring in msg:
  "do something"
else:
  "do something else"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a version of Python older than 2.6 you can use popen, like in the example below.

```
import os
substring = "up-to-date"
msg = os.popen("git pull").read()
if msg.find(substring) == -1 :
   print "do something"
```

Comment: ```os.popen``` is deprecated as of 2.6